# $resouce query with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I'm learning Angular and was building a service which uses $resource to work with data.  I'm able to use query() to get a list of data, but now I wanted to filter it down to just a list of specific items.  I've created a method in my asp.net MVC code to get called, it takes 2 parameters (sectionId and typeId) but I don't see the method being called by angular.  My breakpoints are never hit in my asp.net code.  My angular call is below:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

testModule.factory('InventoryRepository', ['$resource', InventoryRepository]);

function InventoryRepository($resource) {
    return {
        get: function (sectionType, typeId) {
            return $resource('/mySite/GetInventoryGrid/:sectionType/:typeId', {sectionType: '@sectionType', typeId: '@typeId'}, {
                query: {method: 'GET', isArray:true}
            }).query();
        },
        save: function (inventoryItem) {
            return $resource('/mySite/SaveInventoryItem').save(inventoryItem);
        },
        remove: function (inventoryItem) {
            return $resource('/mySite/RemoveInventoryItem').save(inventoryItem);
        }
    }
}
})();
```

the save and remove methods work fine, i'm just not sure how to get the query to work with parameters.  this result is then returned to my calling controller:

```
vm.Inventories = InventoryRepository.get(sectionType, typeId);
```

I see the call does work as my breakdowns in Chrome do get into the get method of the InventoryRepository.  Using Fiddler I see the call made with a 500 return, it appears to not have passed the parameters along.

Update, I fixed it by changing the following:
from my controller:

```
vm.Inventories = InventoryRepository.get({ sectionType: sType, typeId: typeId});
```

and my service get method to:

```
            get: function (params) {
            return $resource('/mySite/GetInventoryGrid?sectionType=:sectionType&typeId=:typeId', { sectionType: '@sectionType', typeId: '@typeId' }, {
                query: {method: 'GET', isArray:true}
            }).query({ sectionType: params.sectionType, typeId: params.typeId});
        },
```

I didn't realize that the get method call was combining the 2 params into 1 object when it was passed into get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the parameter's to `query()` method.

```
get: function (sectionType, typeId) {
    return $resource('/mySite/GetInventoryGrid/:sectionType/:typeId', {sectionType: '@sectionType', typeId: '@typeId'}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray:true}
    }).query({sectionType: sectionType, typeId: typeId});
             ///^^^^^^^^
},
```